# Freeform file upload question

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We are using Freeform to allow users to apply for jobs, and we want to be able to allow them to send attachments (restricted to pdf or docs only).

How does Freeform handle multiple files with the same file name? If more than one person uploads a file called "resume.pdf", for example, does the newer one overwrite the old? Or are the files sorted in such a way as to prevent this type of situation?

Comment: You would have had your answer quicker than it took you to type this question if you just tried it out :p I'm not sure, I might be able to check for you if for some reason you can't.

Comment: Ok, yes, I should have just tested this first. Didn't know if anyone simply knew this offhand.

Answer (score 2):

If two files are uploaded with the same file name, the file names are adjusted so one does not overwrite the other. In testing this out, I uploaded two files called sample.pdf. The second one simply got retitled to sample1.pdf.